# How to get the eigenvalues of Hamiltonian in an over complete basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, linear-algebra

Let $|\psi_i\rangle$, $i=1...N+m$, be a set of overcomplete basis vector in a $N$-dim Hilbert space. The following are known: (Einstein's summation convention assumed)
$$\hat{H}|\psi_i\rangle=H_{ji}|\psi_j\rangle$$,
$$\lambda^\alpha_j|\psi_j\rangle=0,\alpha=1..m$$ 
$$\langle \psi_i|\psi_j\rangle=S_{ij}$$
We already know the numerical values of $H_{ij}, S_{ij}, \lambda^\alpha_j$. Then how to find the eigenvalues of $\hat{H}$ using the common Matlab or Mathematica functions?

Comment: @Lagrenge After giving this few seconds of thought, I'd say 1. diagonalize S, 2. project S and H to eigenvectors of S with non-zero eigenvalues. Sometimes such basis set 'purifications' (I can't remember the official word right now) are done in basis set codes to avoid numerical instabilities with nearly linearly dependent basis.

Comment: Your notation seems a bit odd to me. But, in any case, it seems that you need to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem.